# Two Subsets of Squares of Reciprocals of Primes with Equal Sums

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $$A=\{\frac{1}{2^2},\frac{1}{3^2},\frac{1}{5^2},...\}$$ be the set of squares of the reciprocals of prime numbers.

We have
$$\sum_{x\in A}x < \infty$$
Do there exist $B \subset A$, $C \subset A$, $B \cap C = \emptyset$, such that 
$$\sum_{x\in B}x = \sum_{x\in C}x  \ \ \ \ \ ?$$
It is important that we deal with primes and not with all natural numbers, otherwise we would have infinitely many solutions with both $B$ and $C$ finite, as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#n_=_%E2%80%932), a type of solution which cannot solve this problem by W-t-P's answer below.

Comment: The answer is pathologically *yes*; take $B=C=\varnothing$. These are the only *finite* sets with this property. There are infinitely many solutions with $B$ and $C$ infinite.

Comment: If it is allowed partitioning the indices in $3$ disjoint sets $B,C,D$ with $\sum_C = \sum_D$, then I guess it is possible for any sequence $x_k \to 0$ such that for some $r 
 > 1/2$, $\forall k \ge K,x_k \ge r^{k/2}$.

Comment: @reuns can you please give more details? What is the sequence $x_k$?

Comment: @Servaes can you please add detail? Do you have an example of infinite $B$ and $C$ which have equal sums?

Comment: I more or less had Jack D'Aurizios original answer in mind, though his revised answer shows that neither sequence can contain $p=2$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is negative. Let $C=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^2}$. This constant is approximately $\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{5}{2}$ due to Euler's product, leading to:
$$ \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^2}\approx \sum_p\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{p^2}}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)}. $$
Assume that the set of prime numbers can be partitioned as $U\cup V$ with $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $U,V\neq\emptyset$. 
We may assume without loss of generality that $2\in U$, hence
$$ \sum_{p\in U}\frac{1}{p^2}\geq \frac{1}{4} > \frac{1}{2}\sum_{p\in U\cup V}\frac{1}{p^2}=\frac{C}{2} $$
which contradicts
$$ \sum_{p\in U}\frac{1}{p^2}=\sum_{p\in V}\frac{1}{p^2}.$$

Comment: @co.sine: actually I was completely wrong before, I have fixed the answer.

Comment: BRILLIANT, Jack D'Aurizio. For the constant $C$: https://mathoverflow.net/a/53444/102549

Comment: What about the case $U \cup V \subsetneq \{\text{primes}\}$?

Comment: I'd rather lean to believe your original answer: we do not have to *partition* the set of all primes, but only want to find two disjoint subsets thereof.

Comment: For $U$, the sum must be at least $1/4$. $C<1/2$, so the maximum sum for $V$ must be less than $1/4$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $B$ and $C$ (are finite and) have the required property, denote by $P$ the product of all primes $p$ with $1/p^2\in B$, and by $Q$ the product of all primes $p$ with $1/p^2\in C$. Then the LHS of $\sum_{x\in B}x=\sum_{x\in C}x$ would be a rational number which, reduced to its lower terms, has its denominator equal to $\prod_{p\in P} p^2$, while the RHS has the denominator equal to $\prod_{p\in Q}p^2$. By the uniqueness of prime decomposition, we would then have $P=Q$, a contradiction.

Comment: What if $B$ and $C$ are empty or infinite? The latter is the interesting part of the question really, as your argument shows.

Comment: @Servaes: I believe that in this case equality is possible, but this would be a little technical to explain in details.